# Magento 2 Product page seprate Custom Option, swatch color and Add to cart product page

Tags: magento2, addtocart

I have a requirement of customization of product layout page.

I created custom options on configurable product page which have also swatch color option.Now I want to move these blocks on bottom section on page layout.
I want to swatch images and custom options of product page with one place while add to cart button on another place.

We are move element and able to separate these blocks but I am not able to add to cart button clickable because of **product-add-form**.

As per Magento2 Standard product page swatch,custom option and add to cart should one place in  **product-add-form** .

Please suggest how can we separate these blocks?

Comment: Have you get any solution ?

Comment: @KirtiNariya,yes I resolved that problem.